# Is there a way to distinguish integers from very near decimals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Look at those evaluations (actual dump from node 0.10.33)

```
> parseFloat(2.1e-17) === parseInt(2.1e-17)
false
> parseFloat(2.1e-17 + 2) === parseInt(2.1e-17 + 2)
true
> parseFloat(2.000000000000000000000000000000000009) === parseInt(2.00000000000000000000000000000000000009)
true
```

**How can I tell integers from decimals *very near* to integers?**

It seems that JS (or at least V8) doesn't care about digits smaller than 10^-16 when doing calculations, even if the 64bit representation used by the language ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)) should handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are pretty much straight forward to explain. First thing to note is, that `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` take a string as an input. So you inputs first get converted to string, before actually getting parsed.

The first is easy to see:

```
> parseFloat(2.1e-17) === parseInt(2.1e-17)
false

// look at the result of each side
parseFloat(2.1e-17) == 2.1e-17
parseInt(2.1e-17)  == 2
```

When parsing the string `"2.1e-17"` as integer, the parse will stop at the dot as that is no valid digit and return everything it found until then, which is just `2`.

```
> parseFloat(2.1e-17 + 2) === parseInt(2.1e-17 + 2)
true

// look at the result of each side
parseFloat(2.1e-17 + 2) == 2
parseInt(2.1e-17 + 2)  == 2
```

Here the formula in the parameter will be evaluated first. Due to the limitations of floating point math (we just have 52bit for the mantissa and can't represent something like `2.000000000000000021`), this will result in just `2`. So both `parseX()` function get the same integer parameter, which will result in the same parsed number.

```
> parseFloat(2.000000000000000000000000000000000009) === parseInt(2.00000000000000000000000000000000000009)
true
```

Same argument as for the second case. The only difference is, that instead of a formula, that gets evaluated, this time it is the JavaScript parser, which converts your numbers just to `2`.

---

So to sum up: From JavaScript's point of view, your numbers are just the same. If you need more precision, you will have to use some library for arbitrary precision.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I'll actually come to the conclusion that `2e-17 + 2` is rounded because its binary representation [needs more](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%2810%5E16%29) than the 52bit mantissa provided by a 64bit double.
If you add this detail in your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @mattecapu `2e-16` can actually be represented without a problem. The problems start, when you try to evaluate `(1 + 2e-16) `.

Comment: @mattecapu Ah ok. Added a sentence for the bit representation.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I learned from ReSharper

instead of using expressions like

```
 if (2.00001 == 2) {}
```

try

```
if (Math.abs(2.00001 - 2) < tolerance) {}
```

where tolerance should be an aceptable value for you for example .001

so all values wich difference is less than .001 will be equals

**Do you really need 10^-16 precision I mean that is why 1000 meter = 1 kilometer, just change the unit of the output so you dont have to work with all those decimals**

Comment: The problem is the difference will always be zero if they differ from less than 10^-16, and I'm looking for a way to compare two numbers deeper

Comment: so multiply it by a big number

Comment: It doesn't work, as I state in the question, operations literally cancel out digits smaller than 10^-16

Comment: do you really need 10^-16 precision I mean that is why we have 1000 meter and 1 km, just change the unit of the output so you dont have to work with all those decimals

Comment: Yes, I need it, and anyway multiplying it doesn't change anything since the number is represented in the same way, as explained in [the reference I linked in the question](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: I dont know how your code works, but i guess you ask a user for some parameters, insted of asking for inches ask for microinches, that is how you wont get those small numbers(or convert inches to microinches in your code). its all about the units

Comment: Changing units won't solve the problem. The problem is about *precision*, how many digits I need to store? If it's more than 16 digits, [64bit numbers don't suffice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869799/is-there-a-way-to-distinguish-integers-from-very-near-decimals-in-javascript/26870025#comment42299284_26870025). However if I need to use `2e-300`, 64bit-numbers are totally fine because they store only 2 and 300, and they don't care about all the zeros. That's [floating point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: doubles are not infinite, they have a limit too, units is the problem, but you will find it later, I mean instead of using  .0000000001 meters use 1 nanometer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp

Comment: Yes, theoretically you have a limit of `+- 2^11 - 1` for the exponent, but that's not the concern here. Precision is independent from the number "size",  and the reason we use floating point arithmetic is just that. Please check the Wikipedia page I linked before.